# useSelector dosen't seem to be updated immediately due to reducer state changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I have a structure(nested object) that exists in the attached image and if I want to change the value of info‍‍`[1]` and assign it to info state into the related reducer, but it doesn't update immediately and I think a deep comparison between the previous state and current value didn't occur.

Someone suggested the immutable js but I don't how to use it.
honestly, I've converted assigning a value(the assigned value to info state after triggering action) to List imported from immutable js because of changing the reference address of the prev state and new value but I didn't get the result.

[image]

I prepared a sandbox for it:
[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-shape-0dthhy)

I expect when I select the cells then push the increase button, selected cells increase one unit increase immediately but it doesn't happen and you must refresh the window to see the changes.